# AT+CMGR retuns ok but no message

Tags: sms, putty, at-command

I have a Huawei K3520 that I can successfully send SMS using AT commands via putty.

When I try to retrive a message using

```
AT+CMGR=1
```

I get an output of

```
OK
```

But no message. I tried 1 though to 3. 1 & 2 get a response of ok and 3 get COMMAND NOT SUPPORT

Other code i have tried is.

```
AT+CMGL="ALL"
```

And output was error

Is there anything else I can try to read SMS via AT?

I know SMS can be read as the venndor software (Vodaphone) that came with it has a part to send and receive SMS and read the phonebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted... helps if you put it into "text mode" first

```
AT+CMGF=1
```